# enable/disable input field and link base on button

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular6

Signup form for a user, there are 2 forms

1. user signup form
2. user OTP

I want to enable OTP input field and resend OTP link of the 2nd form (user OTP Form), when a user clicks on the submit button of the user signup form.

[image]

```
Submit button of user-details-form
<button class="submit-btn" type="submit" [disabled]="!userSignupForm.valid"> Submit </button>

OTP Input field of OTP User form <input matInput placeholder="otp" formControlName="otp" required >

OTP button link of OTP User
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="resendUserOTP()" >Resend OTP</a>
Attachments area
```

Comment: Just a guess... seems that a button would be more suitable than a tag, as there are no interferences with routing?